# Software Protection Provider Service Re-enabled Automatic Updates

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-update, automatic-updates, software-protection

We have run into an issue where there are corresponding event viewer entries that show something regarding Security-SPP at the same time the windowsupdate.log file started writing its checks for automatic updates.

Prior to that entry, the update settings were set by Group Policy. My question: Is it possible for Security-SPP to re-enable automatic updates and/or override what has been determined for group policy?

Answer (score 0):

I have been informed by a number of individuals that the windows update service must have its startup type set to "DISABLE" or it runs the risk of getting started by another service such as SPP or other AV programs.

It is a possible way to protect the system in the case of a zero day or other important update.